# Cakephp autocomplete populate multiple fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, cakephp, autocomplete, cakephp-2.3

I have followed this tutorial for creating autocomplete for my form:

http://www.willis-owen.co.uk/2012/12/autocomplete-widget-cakephp/#comment-12074

There was some errors, but I got it working perfectly.

Now I want to add fetched data to multiple form fields (type=text) based on the selected company. How can this be achieved? I added more fields to the controller:

```
public function find_company_by_name() {

  $this->Customer->recursive = -1;

  if ($this->request->is('ajax')) {
    $this->autoRender = false;
    $results = $this->Customer->find('all', array(
      'fields' => array('Customer.name', 'Customer.name_2', 'Customer.address', 'Customer.postalCode', 'Customer.postalAddress',),
      //remove the leading '%' if you want to restrict the matches more
      'conditions' => array('Customer.name LIKE ' => '%' . $this->request->query['q'] . '%')
    ));
    foreach($results as $result) {
      echo $result['Customer']['address'] . "\n";
    }


  } else {
    //if the form wasn't submitted with JavaScript
    //set a session variable with the search term in and redirect to index page
    // $this->Session->write('customerName',$this->request->data['Customer']['name']);
    //  $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'dashboard'));
  }

}
```

So nothing special, only added fields to the search clause. Next step is that I have to populate input fields in autocomplete triggering JavaScript. How to do that? Here is my very simple JS:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){  
    $("#invoiceName").autocomplete("http://www.domain.com/application/customers/find_company_by_name.json", {
    minChars: 1
    });
  });
</script>
```

How to get "name_2", "address", "postalCode" and "postalAddress" -fields to the Javascript to populate other fields in the form?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Does anyone has ideas for this?

Answer (score 0):

I did not got any answers, but I figured it out myself, and little guidance from original author Richard Willis-Owen.

Here is CONTROLLER:

```
public function find_company_by_name() {

    $this->Customer->recursive = -1;

    if ($this->request->is('ajax')) {
    $this->autoRender = false;
    $results = $this->Customer->find('all', array('fields' => array('Customer.id', 'Customer.name', 'Customer.name_2', 'Customer.address', 'Customer.postalCode', 'Customer.postalAddress'), 'conditions' => array('Customer.name LIKE ' => '%' . $this->request->query['q'] . '%')));
        foreach($results as $result) {
          echo $result['Customer']['name'].'|'.$result['Customer']['id'].'|'.$result['Customer']['name_2'].'|'.$result['Customer']['address'].'|'.$result['Customer']['postalCode'].'|'.$result['Customer']['postalAddress']."\n";
        }
    } 

}
```

...and here is Javascript from VIEW:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $("#invoiceName").autocomplete("http://www.domain.fi/application/customers/find_company_by_name.json", 
        {
            minChars:       1,
            delay:          0,
            maxCacheLength: 100,
            onItemSelect: 
            function (item) {
                        $("#invoiceCustomerNo").val(item.data[0]);
                        $("#invoiceName2").val(item.data[1]);
                        $("#invoiceAddress").val(item.data[2]);
                        $("#invoicePostalCode").val(item.data[3]);
                        $("#invoicePostalAddress").val(item.data[4]);
                    }
        }
    );
});
</script>
```

Hope this helps somebody struggling with this "challenge" :)